# Swift generic closure

Tags: ios, swift, generics, closures

I'm building a library for static table views and it works fine, but I encountered a problem with generic closures.

It looks like this so far:

```
orderForm = Form(tableView: orderTable) { f in
    f.section { s in
        s.footer("Při platbě nejsou účtovány žádné další poplatky.")
        s.cell("Selection")
            .configure { (cell, path) in
                let c = cell as! ProfileSelectionCell
                c.titleLabel?.text = "Způsob platby"
                c.detailLabel?.text = self.paymentType.first
            }
        s.cell("Selection")
            .configure { (cell, path) in
                let c = cell as! ProfileSelectionCell
                c.titleLabel?.text = "Balíček"
                c.detailLabel?.text = "20 kr. za 1000 Kc"
            }.selected { path in

            }
        }
    }
```

I wanna have the "cell" variable already cast to appropriate type, in this case ProfileSelectionCell.

Here is the source for the cell class:

```
class Cell {
internal let id: String
internal var configure: ((cell: UITableViewCell, path: NSIndexPath) -> Void)?
internal var selected: ((path: NSIndexPath) -> Void)?

init(id: String) {
    self.id = id
}

func configure(config: ((cell: UITableViewCell, path: NSIndexPath) -> Void)?) -> Self {
    self.configure = config
    return self
}

func selected(selected: (path: NSIndexPath) -> Void) -> Self {
    self.selected = selected
    return self
}}
```

My problem is that if I make the configure method generic, it is not possible to store the config closure to the cell variable and if I make the whole cell generic, I can't save the cell to an array in Section class and so on..

Is this solvable in any way?

Comment: In my opinion, such libraries in most cases really overcomplicate every code. If you have static cells, why don't you create them in a storyboard with `UITableViewController`?

Comment: It's not possible to use static tables in UIViewController, otherwise it would be at least somewhat useable. I can't use UITableViewController for most of my forms. And using plain delegates is just pain.

Comment: Have you thought about child controllers? Every `UIViewController` can have `UITableViewController` as its child controller.

Comment: yes, but it's still a lot more work than having these few lines of code, which can even reuse the cells...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `Cell` class generic, e.g.

```
class Cell<T : UITableViewCell> {
}
```

and then use `T` instead of every `UITableViewCell`.

Unfortunately you would have to have the same in both `Section` and `Form` classes, too. That would work for tables with one type of cells but it won't probably work for tables with multiple cell types. In that case you will *always* need casting somewhere.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of :(